# Auction bid increment rule not evaluating correctly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an auction and the seller of the auction listing can set an increment amount. So for example if they set $20.00 as the increment and starting bid as $50.00. Then you could bid $70.00, $90.00, $110.00, etc...
Right now they are instances where the increment rule isn't working. For example if I set starting bid to $25.00 and increment to $15.00 and I bid $40.00, then I get the message:

`Bid does not meet increment requirement rule`

What's wrong with my "if" condition?

```
  if(!bidInput){

    this.toastr.warning('Please enter a bid amount first.', '', {
      timeOut: 2000
    });
    return;

}

if (bidInputNum <= currentBidNum) {
  this.toastr.warning('Bid is lower than current bid.', '', {
    timeOut: 2000
  });
  return;
}

if (bidInputNum % incrementNum !== 0) {
  this.toastr.warning('Bid does not meet increment requirement rule.', '', {
    timeOut: 3000
  });
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate to @ulmas answer,
If you're holding previous bidding value then you could try

```
   if ((bidInputNum - previousBid) % incrementNum !== 0) {
     this.toastr.warning('Bid does not meet increment requirement rule.', '', {
       timeOut: 3000
     });
     return;
   }
```

Note: Initially, previousBid is equal to initialBid.

For example, bid input is $55.00 and previous bid is $40.00 then (55-40=15 which is increment condition).

Comment: I had trouble getting the first answer working, but this worked really well and I did have current bid value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((bidInputNum - initialBid) % incrementNum !== 0) {
  this.toastr.warning('Bid does not meet increment requirement rule.', '', {
    timeOut: 3000
  });
  return;
```

Let's say `initialBid` is the initial bid amount. Substruct that from the bid input first, then do the remainder division `% incrementNum`